# MS Access: Conditional formatting - highlight duplicates

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Is there an expression that I can use in MS Access ,to highlight Duplicate entries in Reports?
I tried something like Expression is : `Count(*)>1` but it doesn't work.

Br,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the original query will need to be bulked up with a sub-query that has an ID column and count of ID.  The outermost query will then need to also return the ID count.

Within the report you'd then need add another field that would show the linked ID count if it was > 1.

Comment: I already have a query that showes me duplicate records 
 `...OR (((Object.Key) In (SELECT [Key] FROM [Object] As Tmp GROUP BY [Key] HAVING Count(*)>1 )));`   I am looking for a Formatting Expression that could help me highlight this entries.

Answer (score 0):

Access reporting (and forms) allows conditional formatting to be used in a similar way to excel.

See Ribbon: Report Design Tools>Formt>ControlFormatting...

It will let you change the format of a control depending on the value it, or another control, contains.

It's a very nice feature and will also let you add bar charts to you list forms to graphically represent the values sorted in a control.

However, the data set will need to have a column that indicates whether the current row has duplicate records.  The snippet from you current query that you provided (that I repeat below) will not do this:

```
 ...OR (((Object.Key) In (SELECT [Key] FROM [Object] As Tmp GROUP BY [Key] HAVING Count(*)>1 )));
```

Without seeing the whole query I can't really help much, but you will need to remove the use of IN and make the SELECT statement a subquery of the main SQL Statement.  The main query resultset will need to be  LEFT JOINED to the sub query using the Key field.  Because of the LEFT JOIN you can use "isnull(Key)" in the SELECT clause and isnull(Key) will be true for non-duplicate rows.

You can then refer to thiscolumn in your conditional formatting

I hope this makes some sense.

You

Comment: Did you find the above useful?  If so please flag as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty way to highlight duplicate data:

1. Select the object you want to highlight if it's duplicated, and make 
   the background white (or whatever the colour of your background is).
2. Create a *copy* of the object that you want highlighted if it's
   a duplicate.
3. Format the copy so it has a highlight, and/or add extra text 
   (eg:  **DUPLICATE**)
4. Put the copy *behind* the original (so it can't be seen).
5. On the original object, select "Hide duplicates" in properties.
6. Ensure "Hide duplicates" is NOT selected on the copy.

So when the duplicate appears, Access will hide it, but then the object you've created that was originally hidden beneath now becomes visible - effectively highlighting the field.

(Unfortunately it will only highlight the field itself, not the entire section.)